# Missing slab.h from linux includes - Ubuntu 16 VM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm working on a linux kernel driver and need access to the kmalloc and kfree functions. From my research these should be available in the slab.h header, but that file doesn't exist in my filesystem.

I tried updating my includes using this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files but it shows that I already have all relevant files.

My system is a VMWare Ubuntu 16.04 installation running kernel 4.15.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need kernel kernel header, and not ones that called UAPI. Usual path where those headers are located (perhaps as a symlink to somewhere else) is */lib/modules/<VERSION>/build*. To make a module you do *make -C ...path from above... M=$PWD modules* in the your driver source tree folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple demo module that calls `kmalloc` and `kfree`:

**demo.c**:

```
#define pr_fmt(fmt) "demo: " fmt

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init demo_init(void) {
    void *buf;

    buf = kmalloc(1000, GFP_KERNEL);
    pr_info("kmalloc returned %p\n", buf);
    kfree(buf);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit demo_exit(void) {
}

module_init(demo_init);
module_exit(demo_exit);
```

**Makefile**:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# KBuild part of Makefile

obj-m += demo.o

else
# Normal part of Makefile
#

# Kernel build directory specified by KDIR variable
# Default to running kernel's build directory if KDIR not set externally
KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M=`pwd` modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M=`pwd` clean

endif
```

You can just run `make` to build the module for the currently running kernel version:

```
$ make
```

Or you can set `KDIR` to build the module for an arbitrary kernel version (defined by `${KERNELVER}` in the following example):

```
$ make KDIR="/lib/modules/${KERNELVER}/build"
```

(If `KDIR` is unspecified, the Makefile sets it to the build path for the currently running kernel: `` "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build" ``.)

If it builds successfully, then you definitely have the kernel headers installed!

To test the module, run:

```
$ sudo /sbin/insmod demo.ko
$ sudo /sbin/rmmod demo
$ sudo dmesg
```

There should be a message on the kernel log similar to this showing the return value from the `kmalloc()` call:

```
[TIMESTAMP] demo: kmalloc returned xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The module also calls `kfree()` to free the allocated block.